# Why is enum cast on short possible but not boxed generic enum cast?

Tags: c#, generics, enums, casting

I just encountered a weird restriction while porting explicitly typed code in a converter to generic code:

When having a `short` (`Int16`) it is possible to cast it to an enum type. When doing the same with a generic enum type and boxed cast (`(T)(object)value`) this is an invalid conversion.

I was able to make the conversion successful by adding a third cast. It now looks like this:

```
Int16 numericValue;
...
var enumValue = (TEnum)(Object)(Int32)numericValue;
```

Why is that? The following (old) code worked just fine:

```
Int16 numericValue;
...
var enumValue = (MyEnum)numericValue;
```

Comment: Do you know for sure that the underlying type of `TEnum` will be `int` (`Int32`)? If the underlying type had been `short` (`Int16`), your initial approach could have worked.

Comment: it's default, so probably int,  but I don't see a reason why I shouldn't change it to short in my use case

Comment: Otherwise, here are some other ugly options for you that should work regardless of the underlying type: `var enumValue = (TEnum)Enum.ToObject(typeof(TEnum), numericValue);` or `var enumValue = (TEnum)(dynamic)numericValue;`

Comment: actually i like the first one better than my triple cast :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem of boxing and unboxing. When you unboxing the object, you can only unbox to the type of the value that was originally boxed:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

In your case, you box an Int16 to an object:

```
Int16 numericValue;
...
var boxedValue = (object)numericValue;
```

and then you try unbox it as an Int32 (enum is Int32) and this is not possible:

```
var enumValue = (TEnum)boxedValue; // -> System.InvalidCastException
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I'll take a look at it

Comment: A slight correction: an enum can be backed by any integral type (`enum E : short { ... }`). The default if not specified, however, is indeed `int`. Generic code that must be able to convert any old `Object` to any old `Enum` is rather nasty.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert: thanks, this is very helpful with `enum E : short ...`